# Intercepting clicks on a knockout radio button

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, radio-button

edited to add:

here is the only way I've managed to make it work at the moment - I took the ko implementation of the 'checked' binding and made a few small mods. Seems a bit heavyweight and prone to breaking when the framework gets updated but hey ho...

[working code pen](http://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/yOPYdL?editors=1010)

---

I have a collection of radio buttons backed off with a knockout vm. If a user attempts to change the selection, I would like to first present them with a confirmation window (i.e. 'are you sure?').

I have managed to make this work, but I'm not happy with the solutions - one was too complex, the other showed two radio buttons selected when the confirmation window appeared.

I would like to intercept the click so that the confirmation shows before the selection changes in the UI (or the backing observable). I've tried to use the mouseup or mousedown event bindings but nothing I do prevents the selection occurring after choosing to cancel the change.

Is it possible to intercept the click and prevent the change propagating if required?

js:

```
var model = {
  checkboxOptions : ["yes","no","maybe"],
  selectedOption : ko.observable(),
  showConfirm:function(data,ev){
    if(!confirm("go ahead?")){
      //doesn't work
      ev.stopPropagation();
      ev.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }  
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

html:

```
<p>
<!-- ko foreach:checkboxOptions -->
<input type="radio" data-bind="event: {mouseup:$parent.showConfirm, click:null, mousedown:null}, value:$data,checked:$parent.selectedOption"/><span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
</p>
<p data-bind="text:selectedOption"></p>
```

[codepen here](http://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/Xdzbzx?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the way knockout checked binding works I would probably customise it with a bindingHandler, something like

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="radioWithConfirm: { selected: $parent.selectedOption }, value: $data"/>

ko.bindingHandlers.radioWithConfirm = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor();

    $(element).on('click', function(event) {
      if (!confirm('really?')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      } else {
        options.selected(this.value);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGPdbq?editors=1010)

Comment: sadly, it still suffers from the double-selection problem. in fact, if you select 'OK', it's possible to get a triple selection!

Comment: Try this instead, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGPdbq?editors=1010. The point I was trying to make is that if you want to change the behavior of how radios should work I don't think the best way is to override knockout native behavior but instead solve it in a bindinghandler and leave the knockout implementation out of it.

Comment: it's better but it still shows double-selection when the confirm is visible. I'm not overriding knockout native behaviour with my working version, it's a custom binding, the majority of which is copied from the native checked binding.